# how to get NavLink inside of a list working?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, nav

This is the code I am working on, this is within a list

```
@foreach(var item in list){
<NavLink href=link>@item.Name</NavLink>
}
```

I would like link to be "mylink/item.Id", however I have tried the following with no success:

1. Create a variable called link `private string link = "mylink/"` and then `href = @(link +item.Id)`.
2. `href=@("mylink/+item.Id")`
3. ```
   href="mylink/{@item.Id}"
   ```

and a few others, but all I have gotten is an error "can't mix markup with c# code", so I am completely lost here, any help?

This is a Razor page, with Blazor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
@foreach(var item in list){
    var link = $"mylink/{item.Id}"; 
    <NavLink href=@link >@item.Name</NavLink>
}
```